# How to make the last TableRow visible?

Tags: android, listview, tablelayout

Picture of the android interface: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=avht6w&s=6

As seen in the picture above I want a small borders at the bottom and top of the white listView. The problem is, as I set the tableRow to be android:paddingBottom="20dp" the border never gets displayed at the bottom. It seems like, if the listviews height is big enough, nothing else after it will get displayed (See code example below to understand).

I have tested some different approaches to solve the problem, one is setting the paddingBottom attribute in the next TableRow (the borders tableRow) but it will only work if the listView's height is exact of the screens height and not to big.

Why do I set the listView's height to a fixed number like 415dp? Well, it is due to another problem I do not know how to solve. If I for example set the listViews height to fill_parent the background will only cover the number of items in the list. I always want the lists background to be filled down to 20dp from the bottom of the interface.

If anyone has some ideas how I can managed to display the border at the bottom and always have the lists background visible, even if it is not filled with items, please post your ideas! /thanx alot!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/orginalbild"
android:gravity="center|top"
android:stretchColumns="1"
android:weightSum="1.0" 
android:fillViewport="true">

<TableRow
    android:background="#000000"
     >
<TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="0.15dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="#999999"
     android:layout_weight="1">
</TextView>


</TableRow>


<TableRow
    android:background="#999999"

    >
<TextView
    android:background="#999999"
    android:id="@+id/show_task_feedback_title"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="28dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.8"
    android:text="@string/LatestFeedbackTitle"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="17dp"
    android:shadowColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0.15dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"> 
    </TextView>

   <TextView

        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.08"  >
    </TextView>


 <Button
        android:id="@+id/latest_feedback_help_button"
        android:layout_width="0dip" 
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/help_button"
        android:layout_weight="0.12"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0.15dp"
         />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
android:background="#212421">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginTop="0.15dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
</TextView>
</TableRow>   



<TableRow>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.25" />
</TableRow> 


<TableRow
android:paddingLeft="24dp"
android:paddingRight="24dp">  <--------THE BLACK BRODER AT THE TOP OF THE LISTVIEW

           <TextView
                android:background="#000000"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </TextView>

         </TableRow>

 <TableRow
android:paddingLeft="24dp"
android:paddingRight="24dp"
android:paddingBottom="20dp" <------(paddingBottom attribute which causes the problem)
>
       <ListView

                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:id="@+id/bookmarks_list"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="415dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="1"
               />
       </TableRow>

  <TableRow>  <---THE BLACK BRODER AT THE BOTTOM OF THE LISTVIEW(not being displayed)

      <TextView
                android:background="#000000"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </TextView>
        </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/orginalbild"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:gravity="center|top"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    android:weightSum="1.0" >

    <TableRow android:background="#000000" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0.15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#999999" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:background="#999999" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/show_task_feedback_title"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0.15dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:background="#999999"
            android:shadowColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="@string/LatestFeedbackTitle"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="17dp" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.08" >
        </TextView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/latest_feedback_help_button"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0.15dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.12"
            android:background="@drawable/help_button" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:background="#212421" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0.15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffffff" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.25" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:paddingTop="0.5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0.5dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/bookmarks_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:entries="@array/listitems" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```